# When to use convertRowIndexToModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have some JDialogs displaying JTables.
When the header columns are clicked a sort occurs on that column.
My question is : how can I know when a column header has been clicked and thus made a sort active.
When the sort is active, I know I should user the `.convertRowIndexToModel` method. 
But how do I detect that a column is sorting in order not to mess the correct index if no sort is active?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, you should ALWAYS uses the `convertRowIndexToModel` when you take an index value from the view (`JTable`) and try and look up some value within the model.  The `JTable` does this automatically when you use it's methods, but incase you're not, you need to take care of it yourself.

There's no need to know if the view is sorted or not...

If you "really" want to know when a table is sorted, you could attach a [`RowSorterListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/RowSorterListener.html) to the `TableRowSorter` used by the table.

You could also use the [`TableRowSorter#getSortKeys`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultRowSorter.html#getSortKeys()) to see which columns are included in the sort...

Comment: Ahh ok. I thought using this conversion was giving correct results only when sorting.  Many thanks, I can see the light now ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have used it for my selection table. When the auto order is activated (`setAutoCreateRowSorter(true)`)
the indices of the model table and the visual change, so you have to tell it to look for it within the model with respect to the one you are seeing.
`((CustomTable)form.getAvailListView().getModel()).data.get(form.getListView().convertRowIndexToModel(i))`